# Java how to read a txt file and make each line it's own string array

Tags: java, arrays, file-read

I have an assignment where I have to read data from a text file and sum up the data in each line. Here is the txt file:

```
Chen Ruolin     9.2 9.3 9   9.9 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8    
Emilie Heymans  9.2 9.2 9   9.9 9.5 9.5 9.7 9.6    
Wang Xin        9.2 9.2 9.1 9.9 9.5 9.6 9.4 9.8    
Paola Espinosa  9.2 9.3 9.2 9   9.5 9.3 9.6 9.8    
Tatiana Ortiz   9.2 9.3 9   9.4 9.1 9.5 9.6 9.8    
Melissa Wu      9.2 9.3 9.3 9.7 9.2 9.2 9.6 9.8    
Marie-Eve Marleau   9.2 9.2 9.2 9.9 9.5 9.2 9.3 9.8    
Tonia Couch     9.2 9   9.1 9.5 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.6    
Laura Wilkinson 9.7 9.1 9.3 9.4 9.5 9.4 9.6 9.2
```

A list of names and diving scores. We're supposed to read the data from the file and put it into arrays (I'm guessing each line would be it's own array), drop the highest and lowest scores of each diver and sum up the remaining scores. So, the output for the first line would look something like this:

```
Chen Roulin: 56.90
```

The thing I'm stuck on is how to take a line and create an array (a string array, in this case) where it would separate the words and numbers and put them each into an array index. To make it more clear, the array for the first line would be something like:

```
String chenRoulin[] = {"Chen", "Roulin", "9.2", "9.3", "9", "9.9", "9.5", "9.5", "9.6", "9.8};
```

With this, I think I would be able to Double.parseDouble the numerical values in the array and sum them up as I explained earlier. I am aware of 2d arrays and have already tried that approach, but was stuck on the same problem, since all the examples I've found so far were creating int or double arrays. Basically, what would be the best/simplest way to make an array out of each line of the file? Thanks in advance for the help. Here's the code I have so far (it's not much):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class DivingData{  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File myFile = new File("diving_data.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    String line = inputFile.nextLine();
    String[] chenRoulin = new String[10];


  }
}
```

Just to be clear, I'm only asking for assistance on one part of this assignment and not trying to get someone here to do it all for me.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, a here's my code, here's my requirement, please solve this, and so you look to be here too early. Much better would be for you to tell us exactly what has you stumped, exactly where you're stuck. Often times the best way for you to do this, and also the best way for you to complete your project is to try to "divide and conquer", to break your big problem into its small constituent steps, and then try to solve each small step one at a time. If a step is especially difficult, then try to subdivide it, and try to solve it in isolation from your big program.

Comment: Have a look at the `StringTokenizer` API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html  - examples: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

Comment: Is it always 8 scores and a 2 word name?

Comment: Myself, I'd create a class, a Diver class, one that has a name String field, and a double[] score array. Then each line would represent one individual Diver object which would be placed in an array of Diver or an `ArrayList<Diver>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
line.split("\\s+");
```

then for each array element you check if you can convert to double. the expression "\s+" looks for white space delimiters like tabs or space char.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing I'm stuck on is how to take a line and create an array (a
>   string array, in this case) where it would separate the words and
>   numbers and put them each into an array index

If this is really the only thing you need help with, just use the split method on the String with a space as parameter:

```
String line = "Chen Ruolin 9.2 9.3 9 9.9 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8";
String[] array = line.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways you can solve your problem : -

1) Going Object Oriented Way - Creating a class with a String field as name and an array of double. Creating an object per line and then process each object.

2) You can also use `Hashmap<String,Double[]>` (Assuming names are unique) and put each line into an entry.

As far as parsing the line is concerned, again there are two ways -

i) One is split method - `line.split(" ")` which would return an array of numbers.

ii) StringTokenizer API in java - See here http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=236